# why does flexslider appears small in section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm try to make my site http://www.vinoecucina.nl responsive.
Everything is working fine except my gallery(#impressie) and the scrollbar(#arrangementen).

```
$("#menu, #arrangementen, #impressie, #reserveren, #contact").hide()

// Selector
var divs = $("#home, #menu, #arrangementen, #impressie, #reserveren, #contact");

// Show chosen div, and hide all others
$("li a").click(function () {
    $("#inhoud").fadeIn();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn(600);
    divs.not(("#" + $(this).attr("class"))).hide();
});

$('nav li a').click(function () {
    $('nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The gallery appears small and the scrollbar(.pane) scrolls the other way.
But when the window resizes everything is working fine. 
And when i delete `.hide` its working fine too, but then I see all the div/pages on the 'first page'.

I tried it with .css display/visibilty/remove but nothing seems to work.
And i tried put height and width(px) on the sections but that's not working too.

Anybody a idea?

The responsive site you can see at http://www.vinoecucina.nl/test/index.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the flexslider, the problem is probably that the images are hidden and the flexslider can't calculate the images height. So why don't you reinit the flexslider after you show the div or fire the plugin when you show the div.

For the scroll I see this in the firebug console, maybe that problem is messing the code:

```
TypeError: $target.position(...) is undefined

scrollTo = scrollTo + $target.position().top + $target.scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following code. I put 'if' in the nav-code and deleted the nanoscroller and flexslider code..

```
    jQuery('#nav a').click(function() {
console.log(jQuery(this).index('a'));
var jQuerydiv = jQuery('.one-threequarter > section').eq(jQuery(this).index('#nav a'));
jQuerydiv.fadeIn();

jQuery('.one-threequarter > section').not(jQuerydiv).hide();

if($("#arrangementen"));
$(".nano").nanoScroller();

if($("#impressie"));
$(".flexslider").resize().flexslider();
```